# Tracking and Monitoring Shortcuts, Commands and Actions

Tags: workflow

Is there a way to track what has been done during work? What buttons/shortcuts used, actions done, tools enabled etc. in sequential order.

Comment: Not very effecient but [screencast](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/editors/info/screen_capture.html#screencasts) is one way I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 2.7x the **Object mode** Tools include a History panel and clicking Undo History or History gives you the list of all your actions, with the most recent one on top. It doesn't include shortcuts. If you want a separate History editor you must wait for the next versions. 
 [image]